# Is there a way to write to the Applescript result?

Tags: applescript

So I was trying to write something to the result tab. Let's just say I tried to make [FizzBuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz#Programming) in AppleScript:

```
repeat with i from 1 to 100
    if i mod 3 is equal to 0 and i mod 5 is equal to 0 then
        return "FizzBuzz"
    else if i mod 3 is equal to 0 then
        return "Fizz"
    else if i mod 5 is equal to 0 then
        return "Buzz"
    else
        return i
    end if
end repeat
```

<sub>I know that there are more optimal ways of writing FizzBuzz, I just wrote it the beginner way for the sake of simplicity</sub>

---

If you were to run this, it just writes to the result page once. I know there is `log`, but there the output appears in the Messages/Events/Replies sections of Script Editor.  I also know that there one could technically store all the values in a variable and then `return` it in the end. I just want to know if there is a way to write something to the Result tab of Script Editor without halting the Script.

Comment: The **Result** _section_ of the **Log** _pane_ in a **Script Editor** _document window_ is designed to show just the _result_ of the last _command_ executed. AFAIK there is no way to change its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The script editor is itself scriptable, so you can use something like the following:

```
repeat with i from 1 to 100     
    if i mod 3 is equal to 0 and i mod 5 is equal to 0 then
        log "FizzBuzz"
    else if i mod 3 is equal to 0 then
        log "Fizz"
    else if i mod 5 is equal to 0 then
        log "Buzz"
    else
        log i
    end if
end repeat

tell application "Script Editor"
    event log of document 1 of window 1
end tell
```

Basically this logs everything the script does and then prints the event log in the results window.

You can also do the following, which is similar, but a bit trickier:

```
start log
repeat with i from 1 to 100
    if i mod 3 is equal to 0 and i mod 5 is equal to 0 then
        log "FizzBuzz"
    else if i mod 3 is equal to 0 then
        log "Fizz"
    else if i mod 5 is equal to 0 then
        log "Buzz"
    else
        log i
    end if
end repeat
stop log
```

But I'm not sure these are really of much use, or consistent with the intent of AppleScript.

Normally if I want an output over time I'd write the output to a file or store it in a variable and then present it at the end of the script. If I really wanted to see it play out in something like real time then I would script TextEdit or BBEdit:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    make new document at end of documents
end tell

repeat with i from 1 to 100
    if i mod 3 is equal to 0 and i mod 5 is equal to 0 then
        printInTextEdit("FizzBuzz")
    else if i mod 3 is equal to 0 then
        printInTextEdit("Fizz")
    else if i mod 5 is equal to 0 then
        printInTextEdit("Buzz")
    else
        printInTextEdit(i)
    end if
end repeat

on printInTextEdit(x)
    tell application "TextEdit"
        tell text of document 1
            set charCount to count of characters
            set character (charCount + 1) to return & x
        end tell
    end tell
end printInTextEdit
```

BBEdit is more scriptable (TextEdit's scripting dictionary is poor), but not everyone has BBEdit installed...

Comment: Running the first piece of code only returns "" for me in the result tab.

Comment: @gurkensaas: really? what OS are you on? it works as written in Big Sur.

Comment: I use Big Sur 11.4 Beta on a MacBook Air. It works if I change it to `tell application "Script Editor" to return event log of document 1 of window 1`.

Comment: @gurkensaas: why are you still using Beta? 11.4 is out...  I did get the "" result on a couple of trials; I fixed it by restarting Script Editor. It might be one of those 'touchy' AppleScript commands.